xlDown stops at line 166 every time
I have to make a small list out of a large data set.
The macros are to delete the unnecessary data and format what is left depending on the list requirements.
Code to select data after unneeded columns are deleted and to format it to a table.
'Fromat to grey scale table and sort by start date (E column) last to first

Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$4:$I$166"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table1"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium4"

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Crew Payroll Bible").ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
    SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Crew Payroll Bible").ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Start Date]]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Crew Payroll Bible").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Worked the first time.
Now the vertical selection from A4 down stops at line 166 every time leaving the rest of the data unselected.
There are no empty cells.
I tried sorting the data file first and again it stops on line 166.

Any reason why you are not using xlUp? You may want to see Find last used cell in Excel VBA

You seem to qualify some Ranges, but not others, best to be consistent. Side note: you want to avoid using  Select in your code.

Empty cells aren't the only thing that will 'stop' xlDown ... another is Table (ie ListObject) boundaries ... the first time you ran your code, presumably, there was no Table in the Worksheet. Your 5th line of code in your question adds a Table so every subsequent time you run your code, xlDown stops at the end of the Table ie row 166.
